# In context to executable compression, are compression softwares like 7ZIP/Winzip considered as executable packers?

Tags: compression, zip, malware-detection

A packer is a tool that compresses an executable file and combine the compressed data with decompression code into a single executable. They are also used to obfuscate malwares. As per my understanding this can also be achieved by using compression softwares such as 7zip/winzip. The list of "**Known executable compressors for Portable Executables**" on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_compression) Wikipedia page does not include softwares such as 7Zip/Winzip.

So are these softwares in any way different from packers ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!
In case of .zip compression user manually extracts the files from the archive whereas the packed executable is like a self extracting archive it contains both packed code and the code required to unpack it. It automatically unpacks itself when executed.